Adding the total number of samples as a row and column to a heatplot
I have written a function which creates heatplots for all datasets within a list (data_list). The plotting works fine, however I don't manage to add the total Nr. of samples as a row and column to the edges of the heatplot.
The dataframes within the datalist all have the same columns and look like this:
A tibble: 6 × 9
  lat_bin lon_bin depth_bin MeanMeasurement_log MeanBiomass_log MeanMeasurementValue MeanBiomass PFG       Depthbin
    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl>           <dbl>                <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1     -79    -174 150                    -1.36          -0.822                0.0505      0.174  Amphipoda      150
2     -79    -173 150                    -0.585         -0.0470               0.688       2.38   Amphipoda      150
3     -79    -165 150                    -1.60          -1.06                 0.025       0.0863 Amphipoda      150
4     -79    -165 400                    -1.51          -0.970                0.031       0.107  Amphipoda      400
5     -78     171 150                    -0.893         -0.355                0.128       0.442  Amphipoda      150
6     -78     178 150                    -1.30          -0.759                0.0635      0.219  Amphipoda      150

My aim is to create a heatplot with Depthbin on the yaxis and lat_bin on the xaxis, which for both axes shows the total Nr of samples of the respective Depthbin and lat_bins as an additional row and column on the heatplot. The function which creates the basic heatplots is copied below. What do I need to add so I can have the samples on the plot as well? Thanks in advance!
heatplot_zonal_average <- function(data_list, heatplot_depth_bins, col_name, depth_col, bin_size = 5) {
  
  # Initiate empty lists to store plots
  plot_list <- list()
  
  for (i in seq_along(data_list)) {
    # i <- 1
    data <- data_list[[i]]
    # filter all the rows which lie inside the selected depth bins
    data <- data[data[[depth_col]] %in% heatplot_depth_bins,] 
    
    # Extract unique PFG value
    pfg_name <- unique(data$PFG)
    
    # Create Lat bins according to custom defined bin size
    data <- data %>%
      mutate(lat_bin_custom = cut(lat_bin, breaks = seq(-90, 90, bin_size))) %>%
      mutate(LatitudeBin = str_remove_all(lat_bin_custom, c("\\(" = "", "\\)" = "", "\\[" = "", "\\]" = ""))) %>% # Remove brackets and parentheses
      mutate(lat_bin_lower = as.numeric(str_extract(LatitudeBin, "^-?[0-9]+"))) # Extract the lower number of the bin 
    
    
    # Calculate sample count for each depth bin
    sample_counts <- data %>%
      group_by(.data[[depth_col]]) %>%
      summarise(n = n())
    
    # Create a data frame for the sample count heatmap
    sample_count_df <- data.frame(
      depth = heatplot_depth_bins,
      n = sample_counts$n[match(heatplot_depth_bins, sample_counts[[depth_col]])]
    )
    
    # Plot the heatmaps
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(lat_bin_lower), y = factor(.data[[depth_col]]), fill = .data[[col_name]])) +
      geom_tile() +
      scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", direction = -1) +
      labs(fill = expression("Ind m"^-3*" (log10)")) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
      scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(-90, 90, by = 4*bin_size)) +
      annotate("text", x = -Inf, y = -Inf, label = pfg_name, hjust = -0.1, vjust = -1, size = 3, color = "black")
    
    # Add the sample count heatmap
    plot <- plot +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Sample Count"))
    
    # Add a line plot for sample counts on the secondary axis
    plot <- plot +
      geom_tile(data = sample_counts, aes(x = 1, y = n), color = "gray50", size = 1.5)
    
    # store the plots for each data set in this list
    plot_list[[i]] <- plot
    
  }
  
  # Combine all plots in one window
  heatmaps <- ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list,
                        ncol = 3, nrow = 5,
                        align = "hv")
  # Add common axis labels to the plot window
  heatmaps <- annotate_figure(heatmaps,
                              top = text_grob(col_name, color = "black", size = 16, face = "bold"),
                              bottom = text_grob("Latitude", color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold"),
                              left = text_grob("Depth", color = "black", size = 14, face = "bold", rot = 90))
  # Save the plot 
  ggsave("heatmaps_zonal_avrg.pdf", path = dir_plots_output, plot = heatmaps, height = 15, width = 13)
  
}


heatplot_zonal_average(data_list, heatplot_depth_bins, col_name = "MeanMeasurement_log", depth_col = "Depthbin", bin_size = 10)  

